# How to pass and receive multiple ajax values in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, keycode

I want to receive multiple values *(sent from file 'edit.php')* in file **`saveedit.php`** through ajax, so that it can be **`inline edited`** but it is not working. Where is the issue?

**`edit.php`**

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        function saveToDatabase(citycode,cityname,stdcode,id) {         
            $.ajax({
                url: "saveedit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:'citycode='+citycode.innerHTML+'&cityname='+cityname.innerHTML+'&stdcode='+stdcode.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    $(cityname).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                }        
           });
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<?php 
    $result=mysqli_query($db,"select * from cities");    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
    <td><?php echo $count+=1; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'cityname','<?php echo $row['id']; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $row['city_name']; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'citycode','<?php echo $row['id']; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $row['city_code']; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'stdcode','<?php echo $row['id']; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $row['stdcode']; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

**`saveedit.php`**

```
<?php
require_once("dbConfig.php");
$ccode=$_POST['citycode']';
$cname=$_POST['cityname']';
$cstd=$_POST['stdcode']';
$id=$_POST['id']';

$result = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE states set cityname= '$cname',citycode= '$ccode',stdcode= '$cstd' WHERE  id=$id");
?>
```

Comment: You have asked two, unrelated questions. Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Ok @Flimzy , my first question is my main priority.

Comment: Please edit this question to ask only one question. You can then ask additional questions for the others.